# Only on the weekend or on the weekend only?

Tags: adverb-placement

1. Free breakfast is available **only** on the weekend.
2. Free breakfast is available on the weekend **only**.
3. Free breakfast is **only** available on the weekend.

It seems that some adverbs like "only" can be placed on different positions.

For above three examples, which one is more idiomatically used? or do they have different meanings too.

Comment: To me as a Brit, they're *all* non-idiomatic. We say ***at** the weekend*, not ***on*** (but we do sometimes use ***on*** with the plural form: *I work on weekends*). But to Americans they're all fine, and mean the same thing. Note that *Only free breakfast is available at the weekend* means something different.